# Dependent pattern matching

Tags: coq

upd. What I would like to do is to put `a = RedNode' ..` into current context (when using `refine`). I found this technique here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316254/coq-keeping-information-in-a-match-statement .

This code works:

```ml
Inductive color : Set := Red | Black.

Inductive rbtree : color -> nat -> Set :=
| Leaf : rbtree Black 0
| RedNode : forall n, rbtree Black n -> nat -> rbtree Black n -> rbtree Red n
| BlackNode : forall c1 c2 n, rbtree c1 n -> nat -> rbtree c2 n -> rbtree Black (S n).

Inductive rtree : nat -> Set :=
| RedNode' : forall c1 c2 n, rbtree c1 n -> nat -> rbtree c2 n -> rtree n.

Definition balance1 n (a : rtree n) (data : nat) c2 (t : rbtree c2 n)
  : { c : color & rbtree c (S n) }.
  refine(
  match a with
  | RedNode' _ c0 _ t1 y t2 => fun Heqa => _
  end (eq_refl a)).
```

My question is in next (slightly modified definition) of `balance1`:

```
Definition balance1 n (a : rtree n) (data : nat) c2 (t : rbtree c2 n)
  : { c : color & rbtree c (S n) }.
refine(
  match a as ax in rtreen nx return a = ax -> _ with
  | RedNode' _ c0 _ t1 y t2 => fun Heqa => _
  end (eq_refl a)).
```

And now coq does not see that `a` and `ax` the same because it is not able to see that `n` and `nx` are the same.

What is going on and how to express equality between `n` and `nx` (so, coq will see I can have `a = ax`)?

(an example is taken from CPDT).

Comment: What I would like to do is to put `RedNode'` into current context (which I see in proof mode when using refine). I found this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316254/coq-keeping-information-in-a-match-statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Pierre Castèran, the first definition works because Coq infers a (useless) return type `ax = ax -> _`. If you really want to maintain an equality like `a = ax` you need to work a bit more to have (a modification of) `a` and `ax` at the same type. The first possibility is to make explicit the equality between the natural number indices and rewrite along it in the return clause:

```ml
(* First possibility: take an equation between the indices as argument
   and transport along that equation *)
Definition balance1 n (a : rtree n) (data : nat) c2 (t : rbtree c2 n)
  : { c : color & rbtree c (S n) }.
  refine(
  match a as ax in rtree nx return
        forall (en : n = nx) (ea : eq_rect n rtree a nx en = ax), _
  with
  | RedNode' _ c0 _ t1 y t2 => fun Heqn Heqa => _
  end eq_refl eq_refl).
Abort.
```

The second possibility, which is a variant on the first used a lot by the [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) library, packs together a natural number with an rtree in a dependent sum, so that the resulting pair has no dependence and equality can be used directly on the pairs:

```ml
(* Variant: pack the index n together with the element a : rtree n
   and take an equation between the packed arguments *)

(* Definition and notation for dependent sum *)
Set Primitive Projections.
Record sigma A (B : A -> Type) := mkSig { pr1 : A; pr2 : B pr1 }.
Unset Primitive Projections.
Arguments sigma {A} B.
Arguments mkSig {A} B pr1 pr2.
Notation "'Σ' x .. y , P" := (sigma (fun x => .. (sigma (fun y => P)) ..))
  (at level 200, x binder, y binder, right associativity,
  format "'[  ' '[  ' Σ  x  ..  y ']' ,  '/' P ']'") : type_scope.

Notation "( x , .. , y , z )" :=
  (@mkSig _ _ x .. (@mkSig _ _ y z) ..)
      (right associativity, at level 0,
       format "( x ,  .. ,  y ,  z )").
Notation " x .1 " := (pr1 x) (at level 3, format "x .1").
Notation " x .2 " := (pr2 x) (at level 3, format "x .2").


Definition balance2 n (a : rtree n) (data : nat) c2 (t : rbtree c2 n)
  : { c : color & rbtree c (S n) }.
  refine(
  match a as ax in rtree nx return
        (n, a) = (nx, ax) -> _
  with
  | RedNode' _ c0 _ t1 y t2 => fun Heqa => _
  end eq_refl).
Abort.
```

In both cases, actually using these equalities afterwards will be somewhat painful: you might be able to use them thanks to decidable equality on natural numbers and its consequences (in particular `UIP_nat` in `Coq.Arith.Peano_dec` if you use the stdlib).

But more globally, you should consider whether maintining such an equality will be really useful for proving your goal: `a` does not appear in the conclusion, nor in any other premise so you should not need to know anything about it beyond its content once pattern-matched.

Comment: Both solutions are just great. Thank you!